# Handwriting of special symbol in maths

Tags: article-writing

What are standard ways of writing the symbol ${\mathbb R}$ in handwriting?

Comment: The way I like to right it is write a normal capital R and a vertical line before it

Comment: I agree with Module. Also, fwiw, I write $\mathbb{C}$ as a normal C with a small vertical line inside and $\mathbb{Q}$ as a normal Q with two small vertical bars inside.